# Cannot configure Null-ls on Neovim

Tags: lua, neovim, formatter, neovim-plugin

I'm new into vim and I'm trying to configure null-ls to format files, I think I'm missing something, since whenever I try to run the command :NullLsInfo to see if I've got a formatter configured, it says that I don't have a buffer source attached.

Here's the NullLsInfos' result for a .vue file, which should support prettier builtin source:
[image]

And here's my null-ls.lua file content, which is correctly sourced in init.vim

```
null_ls = require("null-ls")
null_ls.setup({
  sources = {
    null_ls.builtins.formatting.shfmt,
    null_ls.builtins.formatting.phpcbf,
    null_ls.builtins.formatting.prettier.with({
        filetypes = { "html", "json", "yaml", "markdown", "vue" },
    }),
  },
})
```

Obviously, when I try to format the document using `:lua vim.lsp.buf.formatting_sync(nil, 2000)`, nothing happens.

I tried running the command  `echo executable("prettier")` returns true.

What am I missing?

### Edit

I just discovered this, when I try to open a file, I get this error
[image]
don't ask me how I discovered this just now

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @jschuebel not found an actual solution yet. I'm currently using Coc and prettier to format js/json/html and something else, but still far from an actual global formatter, cannot format php files yet, for example.

Answer (score 0):

What I imagine is happening is that you tried to configure setup twice, first on installation and another on said file, the setup from installation has priority. Just erase or configure correct there. Can't confirm, since you didn't post your installation code.

Also, for good practice, add a 'local' before null_ls

```
local null_ls = require("null-ls")
```

Comment: With installation file you mean the "init.vim"? because the only thing i have there about null-ls is: 
`Plug 'jose-elias-alvarez/null-ls.nvim'` and `source $HOME/.config/nvim/plug-config/null-ls.lua`, and if I try to remove the first part vim throws me an error saying it can't find null-ls.

Comment: I misjudged your "new into vim". Your installation seems fine. Just to make sure, did you install plenary?

Comment: Yep, with `Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'`, I just edited with a new error I just noticed

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem and i fixed it by re-configuring my neovim from the start , if you had no other choice that what i did

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).